# ctrl and space key used in Action script class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I have a switch statement in my action script class.I have a  `function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent)` which contain a switch statement.which control the different keys.
But now I want to handle the same functionality which <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is doing using two keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key.
I want add a case more in my switch statement  first I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key then a a specific function is called.

Anyone can tell me how two keys used in my switch statement?

```
    private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) : void{

        if (popUp.displayPopUp){
            switch (event.keyCode){
                case Keyboard.UP:
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                case Keyboard.END:
                case Keyboard.HOME:
                case Keyboard.PAGE_UP:
                case Keyboard.PAGE_DOWN:
                    inputTxt.selectRange(text.length, text.length)
                    list.dispatchEvent(event)
                    break;
                case Keyboard.ENTER:
                    acceptCompletion();
                    break;
                case Keyboard.TAB:
                    if (requireSelection)
                        acceptCompletion();
                    else
                        popUp.displayPopUp = false
                    break;
                case Keyboard.ESCAPE:
                    popUp.displayPopUp = false
                    break;
                case Keyboard.CONTROL && Keyboard.SPACE:
                    if (requireSelection)
                        acceptCompletion();
                    else
                        popUp.displayPopUp = false
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case Keyboard.SPACE:
if (event.ctrlKey)
{

}
break;

i think this one approch is good........

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common problem.

`event.keyCode` is only going to give you the keyCode for the most recent key pressed. So you will have to store key presses and key releases. Fortunately, AS3 is a pretty sweet Array implementation that allows this to be done easily.

```
var _keys:Array;

addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEvent);
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpEvent);

function keyDownEvent(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    // turn the key on
    _keys[e.keyCode] = true;

    // perform logic
    keyLogic()
}
function keyUpEvent(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    // turn the key off
    _keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}
function keyLogic()
{
    // this is where the actual logic is
    if(_keys[Keyboard.SPACE] && _keys[Keyboard.CONTROL])
    {
        if (requireSelection)
            acceptCompletion();
        else
            popUp.displayPopUp = false
    }
}
```

This allows you to have a neat little array that always tells you what keys are down. It also separates your program logic from your input logic. Double win.

Comment: you may also want to have a look into possible storing the states of keys in the Dictionary class as it's read time is literally always 0ms, the fastest type of associative array in flash.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just check `ctrlKey` property on [KeyboardEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#ctrlKey). But @DingoEatingFuzz's answer will allow check combinations like 'space' + 'letter' and so on.